# Getting error when trying to execute this code for MMT site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have used the following code.I am getting NoSuchElementException error when I am trying to run this code for make my trip site

```
public class suggestiveDropdown_MMTsite {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Actions a = new Actions(driver);

    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));
    a.moveToElement(source).click().build().perform();
    a.moveToElement(source).sendKeys("MUM").build().perform();
    /*WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("react-autowhatever-1")));*/

    WebElement dropdown1 = driver.findElement(By.id("react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"));
    a.moveToElement(dropdown1).click().build().perform();
    WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.id("toCity"));
    a.moveToElement(destination).click().build().perform();
    a.moveToElement(destination).sendKeys("DEL").build().perform();
    a.moveToElement(dropdown1).click().build().perform();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-identify `dropdown1` as the second time it appears it's in a different location in the source an a different webelement.

I see your logic and why you think it would work as it has the same ID - but when you use your `By` you're returning a **specific webelement** from the DOM. Even though the ID is reused due to whatever javascript magic, the **webelement** is different (it's in a different position after all).

The two bits I'm talking about....

1/ This part of your code finds the object:

```
    WebElement dropdown1 = driver.findElement(By.id("react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"));
    a.moveToElement(dropdown1).click().build().perform();
```

2/ It is no longer dropdown 1. It has the SAME ID, but it's a different webelement

```
    a.moveToElement(dropdown1).click().build().perform();
```

Solution here is re-get the element and I suggest to rename it to help clarify the difference. Change your last line to something like this:

```
    WebElement firstItemInToCity= driver.findElement(By.id("react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"));
    a.moveToElement(firstItemInToCity).click().build().perform();
```

---

I've had another look. This works for me:

```
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Actions a = new Actions(driver);

        //from city:
        WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));
        source.click();
        source.sendKeys("MUM");

        //select first item in the list
        WebElement dropdown1 = driver.findElement(By.id("react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"));
        dropdown1.click();

        //Get the to city
        WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.id("toCity"));
        destination.click();
        destination.sendKeys("DEL");
        
        //pick the first item in the list
        WebElement firstItemInToCity= driver.findElement(By.id("react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"));
        firstItemInToCity.click();
```

You do not need to use the actions to interact. Using the selenium native interactions seems fine.

I did have increase the implicit timeout as the page is quote slow to load for me.

Comment: I renamed it . But whenever I try to execute the code I get NoSuchElementException for the this line:

Comment: `code` WebElement fromCityItem = driver.findElement(By.id("react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"));

Comment: once it worked properly but then afterwards everytime I try to execute i get the same error for that line

Comment: It might also need a draw delay between send keys and selecting the top item to let the list buffer - or you need an alternative approach to "selecting the top one" -at the mo it's just a blind select as soon as the send keys is finsihed

Comment: Yes I tried earlier with native interactions  but  for  `code` source.click(); statement , I got ElementClickInterceptedException , so I was trying with Actions for interactions

Comment: @Ziniya does the above work for you? - I've identified your problem, outlined the reason and posted tested and working code for my system. If you're still having trouble would you please edit your original question and be clear on the code you're trying, the error, the line it occurs on and what you need to happen

Comment: Yes the code you posted I tried it and it did work properly. Actually when we initially open the site we get a sign-in popup(when you are not signed in) which was actually causing the issue I think. I wrote few more lines to initially cancel the pop up and then proceed ,with the code you posted and it worked.